# Interview : Unix Code to multiply two numbers

Tags: unix

> write a one line script to multiply any two numbers together.

what is the interviewer looking for?

echo $a * $b

is this sufficient?

Answer (score 8):

In bash and probably a few other shells too, it is as simple as :

```
echo $(( $a * $b ))
```

Comment: Yes, `$(( ))` is defined in the POSIX standard (=> very portable) :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this, expr evaluation is done on fixed-width integers so that wouldn't help if the numbers are not integral.

```
echo 'mult 12.3 5.6' | awk '{ printf("%.4f\n", $2*$3);}'
```

plus, you can also easily format your result with c-style printf.

Answer (score 2):

No, you would've needed to use `bc`:

```
echo "$a * $b" | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Use `bc`, or something like `expr 2 \* 3`. If you do not escape the asterisk, it will have its usual "joker" meaning.

Answer (score 1):

That will only work smallish numbers, 16bit signed non-floating I think. You could use bc, "an arbitrary precision calculator language".

```
echo "$a * $b" | bc
```

Comment: `bc` has _nothing_ to do with `bash` :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way I see multiplying two numbers using Unix commands could be:

echo `expr $a \* $b`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$ echo -e $(($myVar * $anyVar))
```

Note: using bc which is for floating point representation is not required unless needed